# Как программно с помощью intent вызвать экран блокировки из своей activity?

Tags: android

Я хочу открыть новую `Activity` после того, как пользователь разблокирует экран с помощью стандартного экрана блокировки. Это нужно для того, что бы другие люди не смогли открыть мою `Activity`, не зная графического пароля или просто пароля.

Как мне вызвать с помощью `Intent` экран блокировки, используемый на устройстве пользователя по умолчанию?